# openstack: vms exchanging multicast on eth1 fail when one suffers IGMP timeout

Tags: networking, openstack

I have two identical trusty VMs configured with dhcp for eth1.  I installed mgen and configured the mgen scripts to have the two exchange 1 multicast message per second for 360 seconds.  One VM stops receiving packets after 260 seconds (the IGMP Snooping Group Timeout). The second VM keeps receiving messages for the entire period.

I experience the same problem if I use identical CentOS 6.5 VMs.

Why does one work? Why does the other timeout and never recover?

Setup;

- Via havana dashboard, I created a network with a 10.16.1/24 subnet, disabled gateway, enabled dhcp with range 10.16.1.100,10.16.1.120.
- Launched 2 trusty instances, each with two NICS; eth0 for my regular public interface, and eth1 for the 10.16.1/24 subnet.
- Logged into each VM and created eth1.cfg, configured for dhcp

  `auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet dhcp`
- ifup eth1 on each vm
- apt-get install mgen on each vm
- configure one VM with this mgen script

  `0.0 JOIN 224.225.1.104 INTERFACE eth1
  0.0 LISTEN UDP 5104
  10.0 ON 1 UDP SRC 5002 DST 224.225.1.103/5103 PERIODIC [1 512]
  370.0 LEAVE 224.225.1.104
  370.0 OFF 1`
- Configure the other VM with complimentary script

  `0.0 JOIN 224.225.1.103 INTERFACE eth1
  0.0 LISTEN UDP 5103
  10.0 ON 1 UDP SRC 5002 DST 224.225.1.104/5104 PERIODIC [1 512]
  370.0 LEAVE 224.225.1.103
  350.0 OFF 1`
- set route on each VM

  `ip route add 224.225.1/24 dev eth1`
- run script on each VM simultaneously

  `mgen input mcast.mgn`

As mgen runs it prints out the messages received from the other VM.  One VM gets to 260 seconds, and stops receiving;

```
18:50:35.414601 RECV proto>UDP flow 1 seq 251 src 10.16.1.103/5002 dst 224.225.1.103/5103 sent 18:50:35.304360 size 512 
18:52:04.672731 OFF flow 1 srcPort 5002 dst 224.225.1.104/5104
```

The other completes as expected;

```
18:52:04.563455 RECV proto UDP flow 1 seq 341 src 10.16.1.104/5002 dst 224.225.1.104/5104 sent 18:52:04.672341 size 512 
18:52:05.305505 OFF flow 1 srcPort 5002 dst 224.225.1.103/5103
```

What gives?

## UPDATE

Using wireshark on the successful VM shows the following IGMP traffic.

[image: wireshark capture on successful VM]

Note the successful VM is using IGMPv2, while the failing one uses IGMPv3.  I don't understand this as VMs are created identically - same base image - same configuration commands - etc..

Also, performed wireshark capture from the failing VM. Interestingly, it does not capture any of the IGMPv2 packets. This probably explains why it never responds to the Membership Query.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227286/multicast-join-on-linux-and-igmpv3), IGMPv3 should be backwards compatible to v2. However, I did use this information to force the failing VM to also use IGMPv2, and performed another wireshark capture.  The result was that the failing VM still does not receive the IGMP Membership Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add a firewall rule to allow IGMP into the VM.

In Havana/Horizon Access & Security, edit default rules and add a new rule;

- Rule: Other Protocol
- Direction: Ingress
- IP Protocol: 2
- Remote: CIDR
- CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

Might be a copy+paste error, but you may have an error in the route add statement you posted.  The route for the entire multicast range is: 224.0.0.0/4

The route statement you posted can work too, but the first octet of your statement is wrong (you have 225 instead of 224).